# 开一个生日会 explanation as to why 开 is used here?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-structure, simplified-characters

My book says that "to host a party" is written as...
开一个生日会
Example:
她想在家里开一个生日会。

The reason I am confused is because everywhere I look, 开 means to open. However, the book translates it as "to hold". I have been told that the 你好 book, which is what I am learning from, can translate some words in *strange ways* so I guess what I am asking is, if this sentence is correct, why is 开 used?

Answer (score 7):

[开会](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%BC%80%E4%BC%9A) (“to host/attend a meeting”) is an example of a [separable verb](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Separable_verb)—we can add content between the two characters. The 开 relates to the “hosting” whereas the 会 relates to the “meeting”, and the in-between content modifies the 会.

For example, we might say:

> 他在开一个会。  (“He is hosting a meeting.”)
> 我们周五开一个三个小时的会。  (“On Fridays, we host a 3-hour meeting.”)

In the given example, instead of a 会(“meeting”), it’s a 生日会 (“birthday party”), but the same idea applies.

> 开一个生日会 (“to host a birthday party”)
> 爸爸开儿子的生日会。 (“The father hosted his son’s birthday party.)

Alternatively, we can think of 开 itself as an independent verb.

Answer (score 5):

Just as English say -- throw a party.

开 means to start up something, like start up a company -- 开公司.

Comment: 开公司 and 开会 are completely different.  开公司 = 建立公司, establish a company, 开会 = 举行会议 hold a meeting.

Comment: 開 does not mean hold by itself. It is about the commencement. 現在開會 means start the meeting now. "Hold" is an implicit consequence of "Start" a meeting. It's just like 開車, "Start a vehicle". One starts the engine of a vehicle and the vehicle moves. And then one drives the vehicle.

Answer (score 3):

> [开](https://cantoneseplus.com/character/237)

> [6] [v] hold (meeting, exhibition, etc)

开 has different meanings. The translation 'to hold' is not wrong in the context of '开一个生日会' (to hold a birthday party)

**开: to hold (e.g. meeting; concert)**

开会议 = to hold a meeting; 开音乐会 = to hold a concert

开: to open (e.g. door; window)

开: to set up and run (e.g. company; restaurant)

Answer (score 1):

0. For your example, `开` means `开始 (start)`, rather than `打开 (open)`.
1. Originally, `开会` means `(召集)开始（一个）会议` 
   as you will also find `闭会` as the opposite, which means `关闭会议`. (And `休会`, `复会`.)
2. As it is used more frequently, people acknowledge the pattern of `开......会`, 
   other examples like `开庙会`, `开晚会`, etc.
3. Then as "birthday party" is translated as `生日会`, (`会` could be a gathering of people), 
   people just keep the pattern and use `开生日会`, which, in English, means "hold a party".  
   And well, the formal translation of "hold a meeting" should be `召开/举行/举办 一场会议`.
4. Btw, we also say `生日派对` these days though, we keep the same verb and say `"开"生日派对` or `"举办"生日派对`.